# Xbox One Wireless Adapter for Windows 10 with Dualshock 4

Tags: controllers

Can a PlayStation 4 controller connect to the Windows 10 Xbox One Wireless Adapter?

Comment: Why would you expect this to work?

Comment: I don't have the XBO Wireless Adapter, so I can't test it, but I'm pretty sure the answer is "no". After all, the adapter is required for the XBO controller because it uses a proprietary protocol (i.e. not supported by anyone anywhere, except the XBO, its controller, and the appropriate adapter). Considering the DS4 uses standard Bluetooth and can connect to any Bluetooth capable PC (or PC that has a regular Bluetooth dongle), it's unlikely it would support the adapter. Sony never designed the DS4 to work on the XBO, and it already supports the PC.

Comment: Isnt ps4 bluetooth?

Answer (score 2):

**The Windows 10 wireless adapter is specifically designed for the Xbox One controller. As such, it will only work with an Xbox One controller, and not a PlayStation 4 controller. There is, however,  a suitable alternative.**

---

According to [selectbutton.com](http://www.selectbutton.com), PlayStation 4 uses Bluetooth, much like the PlayStation 3. As such, you can connect a PlayStation 4 controller to a computer quite easily, using a separate program to handle input, and Bluetooth controller.

For the input manager, [Input Mapper](https://inputmapper.com/downloads/summary/2-input-mapper/27-inputmapper) is recommended, however for Windows 10 you will also need to apply a fix, in the form of a [Bat file](https://app.box.com/inputmapper-win10-fix). Most computers will have the Bluetooth component built in, these days. You require Bluetooth 4.0, and if your computer does not already have one, they are fairly cheap to buy from your local computer store or electric retailer.

---

These are the instructions, copied directly from [selectbutton.com](http://www.selectbutton.com/features/how-to-use-ps4-controller-on-pc/).

> **How to synch yoour PS4 controller wirelessly**
>
> 1. Hold down the PS logo and share button until the light bar flashes rapidly. This will allow you to sync the controller.
> 2. For Windows 8/8.1 users, in the Bluetooth menu the controller will appear as “ready to pair".
> 3. Click the “ready to pair" button to successfully link the controller to your PC.
> 4. If you need to sync back with a PlayStation 4, turn the console on first, then connect the DS4 with the included USB cable and hit the PS Home button.
>
> **Windows 10 Fix**
>
> 1. Download the "Input Mapper Windows 10 Fix Bat File" and save it to your desktop.
> 2. Open Input Mapper without Steam or any games running (you may want to start it as soon as you boot into Windows 10).
> 3. Run the .bat file, you will notice the desktop has gone black and a command prompt is open.
> 4. Turn on the DS4 (ensuring it appears in Input Mapper) and hit any key to continue once it is connected in Input Mapper.
> 5. If you see a yellow bar (warning about exclusive mode) at the bottom of the Input Mapper window, something is still interfering with the DS4. Close all other programs and repeat steps 2-4.